# What are the Pros and Cons of assigning value for ids from an offset? (Ex: 100,200,1000)

Tags: mysql, database-design, primary-key, auto-increment

Pre-dominantly, everybody uses the `int` data-type or it's variants `tinyint`,`smallint` and `mediumint` to generate a **unique value** for the `id` field of their database table(s).

I have seen so many questions, asking `How to start auto-increment from a value (offset) ?` When it comes to generating ids for *orders* table in specific, I feel everybody wants to start off from an offset.

So, in this context, my questions are:

1. Is it more of a **business rule**? If so, how does a business rule make sense while generating numbers?
2. If it's an **individual's decision** then what could be the possible elements  to be considered while deciding to assign id's value from an offset??
3. Why not start from **1** for all the ids and what is the need to start assigning `ids` from an `offset`? What problem does it solve? What are the **Pros** and **Cons** of doing so?

Comment: E.g. you need an order number which is always **n** digits.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of reasons why you may want an offset. Please be aware, some of these reasons are not necessarily good DBA practice.

1. As dnoeth mentioned, your primary key may be used in some other business process such as an order number. In that case, you don't want your customers thinking they are only the 11th order!  Being order number 1100011 is much better.
2. You may have a old system that is in read only mode.  It has all your old customers in it with their primary keys, and you want the new system to pick up where it left off.
3. Same idea, you know you will be importing PKS of a certain value at some point in the future, so you start with ones you know won't cause a collision.

Personally, the only time I offset is to avoid PK collisions. Sure, there was that one time when I was younger that I just though starting at PK ID 10000 was cool, but that was a long time ago.

Really, there are no Cons of doing so.  Except for some nominal space issues between data types and potentially losing the ability to assign PKs up to the data type limit, the database doesn't care if it starts at 1 or 1,000,000. It is going to index it all the same.

Comment: I'm guessing point 1 is not a good practice as you mentioned. I have gone through posts mentioning it's a bad idea to reveal ids used inside the table. I agree with point 2, makes perfect sense. I couldn't imagine a case where point 3 would be useful in terms of a small sized project. And isn't point 3 an extension of point 2? Help me understand.

Comment: Difference between 2 and 3 is that you may not be importing the data into the new system. Both still deal with collisions.

Comment: 1 Isn't necessarily BAD practice, I just wouldn't consider it good practice.  It just the potential for a large number of headaches down the line.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why you should *not* trust `AUTO_INCREMENT` values to follow any pattern.  They only guarantee to be unique at any moment in time.

There is one particular situation that could be deadly to your application.  If you delete the highest id, then restart mysql, that id *may* be reused.

See also [*More caveats*](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/1748/indexes-and-keys/15274/auto-increment-key)

If you want to build ids in a particular pattern, you must take ownership of the id column.  And be careful -- `ROLLBACK` can trip you up.  Multiple connections can be an issue.

Back to your question (if I have not scared you off)...

```
ALTER TABLE foo AUTO_INCREMENT=200;
```

See also the variables `auto_increment_offset` and `auto_increment_increment`.  (They are *intended* for use in multi-Master replication.)

Manual SEQUENCE:  There is a nice example in the [*ref manual*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html).  (Search that page for 'sequence'.)

Comment: In InnoDB, an id generated by `AUTO_INCREMENT` will always be unique, even if it is not constrained to be `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE`.  Yes, you could _explicitly_ insert a dup into an AI column without the constraint.

Comment: @RickJames : That was some serious information. Thank you. But, I couldn't find a reply for my questions in your answer. I would like to understand the **logical and technical needs** of using the `offset` method to devise `ids` at the moment. Your answer informs me about how to *safely* generate such values. Can you please append the answer with your thoughts on my questions?

Comment: added a line to answer

Comment: I went through the link. It had some good information. But the suggestions leaves me in bit of a surprise! For a project I'm working on, I have close to **30 tables** for which I have to **generate** `ids` for `primary key`. The user base could scale up in a few months and real soon we might go on for a `master-slave`. With this in mind, should I **really really make 30 tables** just to **hold** the value of `auto-incremented` primary keys and use `replace` every-time before I insert a new row with the new primary key?

Comment: I'm using `InnoDB` engine and I went through, `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode `. I thinking of setting the `lock-mode` to `1`. If my anticipations is right, there will be no need for bulk inserts in the system I develop. No legacy data is provided and at the very least I wouldn't be importing it after it's in production. Once scaled up, directing writes to master and reads to the many slaves should do a good job and avoid `auto-increment` problems. Am I right?

Comment: Personally, I would rethink the application requirements -- with the goal of using `AUTO_INCREMENT`, while being aware of its quirks.

Comment: _Today_ there is no bulk insert; _today_ there is no legacy data.  _Tomorrow_...?

Comment: Replication -- do not use Multi-Master where you write to both masters; there will be a new set of problems with auto_inc _and_ "sequences".  Do be aware that there are at least 2 more quirks in auto_inc due to replication.